# How can I use raw litecoin protocol to connect to nodes?

Tags: litecoin, protocol, raw-transaction, nodes, connection

I am trying to connect to litecoin nodes using raw protocol. I follow [Ken Shirriff](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/10341/ken-shirriff) instructions from [this article](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html) . My code works perfect with bitcoin, so I just replaced bitcoin nodes connection parameters with litecoin ones: port for connection and magic number for messages (as I know their protocols are the same), but It doesn't work. Have no idea what's wrong. [Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/30mb1/22e87ed6556c931006c3a3ae53a8988d).